Formatting timestamptz Column to below Format with Custom Timezone Offset in Amazon Redshift
I have a table in Amazon Redshift with a timestamptz column that contains timestamps with various timezone offsets. I need to format these timestamps into a specific ISO 8601 format.
Details:
Column name: timedte
Current format examples:
 '2024-08-26 23:09:11.949000 +05:55'
 '2024-08-26 23:09:11.949000 +00:00'

Desired format examples:
'2024-08-26T23:09:12+0555' (for +05:55 offset)
'2024-08-26T23:09:12+0000' (for +00:00 offset)

Requirements:
For non-zero timezone offsets, format the output as YYYY-MM-DDTHH:MM:SS±HHMM (e.g., 2024-08-26T23:09:12+0555).
For zero timezone offsets (UTC), format the output as YYYY-MM-DDTHH:MM:SS±0000 (e.g., 2024-08-26T23:09:12+0000).
Problem:
I attempted the following query, but it did not produce the expected results:
sql
SELECT
    to_char(timedte, 'YYYY-MM-DD"T"HH24:MI:SSOF') || 
    LPAD(ABS(EXTRACT(TIMEZONE_HOUR FROM timedte::timestamptz))::TEXT, 2, '0') AS formatted_timedte
FROM t;

Issue:
The output is not in the correct format, especially when handling the timezone offsets.
Desired Result:
I need help crafting the correct SQL query that can format the timestamptz column to match the specified ISO 8601 format.
Any guidance or examples would be greatly appreciated!

As I understand ISO 8601, your timezone offset should be in extended format, since the rest of the timestamp is in that format. I.e. YYYY-MM-DDThh:mm:ss±hh:mm.

@jarlh currently from  to_char(timedte, 'YYYY-MM-DD"T"HH24:MI:SSOF') I am only getting '2024-08-26T23:09:12+00', I need '2024-08-26T23:09:12+0000' it seems T is trimming that value.

Try this:
select to_char(timedte::timestamp, 'YYYY-MM-DD"T"HH24:MI:SS') ||
    replace(split_part(timedte, ' ', 3), ':', '')
    as formatted_timedte 
from t;

Using one of your example input strings ('2024-08-26 23:09:11.949000 +05:55'), that outputs
2024-08-26T23:09:11+0555

I am converting to a timestamp (thus dropping the timezone completely), and treating the timezone as a string and concatenating a formatted version to the end. It's kind of hack-y in that it doesn't fully use date or time conversions, but I don't see anything in the docs that supports what you're trying to do.
So the generic case is:
select to_char(<timestamp_col>::timestamp, 'YYYY-MM-DD"T"HH24:MI:SS') ||
    replace(split_part(<timestamp_col>, ' ', 3), ':', '');

